# Template Builder: SOAP Error

Tags: 2013, template-builder

When I use Template builder and I try to debug a component template, I always get the following error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Cannot use this process, it has exited

and

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)

and

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

and

> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.StartDebuggingWithItemUri(String compoundTemplateId, String compoundTemplateXml, String itemId, Boolean includeSystemLog, TraceEventType logLevel)

and

> Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.DebugObject.Start(Template template, Object debugItem, LoggingOptions loggingOptions)

I've checked Event Viewer:

> Cannot use this process, it has exited
>
> Component: CompoundTemplateWebService
>   Errorcode: 0
>   User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:

> Server stack trace: 
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggerRemoteRunner.Ping()
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context around the problem, for starters what version of SDL Tridion are we talking about and does this happen on any template or on a specific template, and in case of the latter, what is happening in that specific template exactly?

Comment: I'm using Tridion 2013 and the problem happens in all the templates.

Comment: You mention debugging, so what process did you connect to in Visual Studio? or is it already happening when yuo simply run a Template in the template Builder?

Comment: Please post what worked (and even accept) if you were able to fix this SOAP issue for Network Service for Template Builder.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you run template builder because similar I faced last time when templating webservice was down, we found and fixed by doing below task:

Only I have selected "Ignore client certificate" from Secure communication section under Directory security tab and found start working.

[image]

Error was:

> The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.Login(Boolean
>   initData)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Model.Login(Uri
>   contentManager, ICredentials credentials)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.UI.CompoundTemplateDesigner.DesignerForm.LogonAs(Uri
>   uri, Exception initialError)